# How to extend the volume control

Tags: android, volume

I would like to extend the volume "control".

Expand with my new "line" to add (also a volume slider);

How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: any more information you could give? your question is kind of short and vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class in the android.view package called VolumnePanel that inflates the volume_adjust_item.xml resource. You can find the VolumePanel.java in /sources/android-/android/view and the volume_adjust_item.xml in /platforms/android-/data/res/layout.

Best of luck.