# Extend Volume Panel in Android

Tags: android, audio, media, chromecast, volume

I'm currently developing an app for casting video to Chromecast. I want to control the Chromecast volume by hardware buttons. Also I want to add my app volume seekbar to the Volume panel (where we have Ring, Media and Alarm seekbars). Actually all of these points already implemented in Youtube Application (see the screenshots).
The closest [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12650446/6083579) which relates to my problem has the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737093/6083579), that I can use somehow `VolumePanel.java`class to achieve this, but I haven't found any samples how to implement this.

---

[image: Customized Volume Panel (what I want to achieve)] [image: Default Volume Panel]

Comment: I don't think you can.  That's a system dialog, your app doesn't put it up.  So you have no hooks to change it.  You may be able to detect the volume up/down buttons and launch your own dialog instead, but only if your app is in the foreground.

Comment: But how is the youtube app behavior explained then?